# How to specifiy sizes of select elements in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for my page.  I have a 3 column layout: span3 span6 span3.  Inside my middle column I want the user to be able to select a date.  I have this so far but all 3 select items are the same exact width.  I want them to be just wide enough to show the text inside them.  Is this possible?

```
<select name="month" id="month" class="span1"></select>
<select name="day" id="day" class="span1"></select>
<select name="year" id="year" class="span1"></select>
```

I populate these programmatically with JavaScript.

Comment: It is possible, have you looked at the `Control sizing` part of the [Forms section](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried that with simple css selector? Determine width with 'inspect element' and add css.
For examp.

```
select#day { width : 250px; }
```